# Employment statistics in Germany since mid-19th century

Tags: economy, germany, statistics, employment

What is the most reliable source of employment statistics in Germany? I am interested in the time period starting from mid-19th century all the way to present days.

Comment: Do you mean the percentage of people with a job or how many people worked in what jobs?

Comment: The [Statistische Bundesamt](https://www.destatis.de/DE/ZahlenFakten/GesamtwirtschaftUmwelt/Arbeitsmarkt/Erwerbstaetigkeit/Erwerbstaetigkeit.html) starts its statistics 1950.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an open ended source request.